# bootstrap datepicker display

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I use  `bootstrap datepicker`.
I add to my html page

```
 <link href="bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

but it not enough, it seems shocking.
[image]

I saw that I should add also `bootstrap.css`
The problem is that it affects my whole page.
What can you do?

Also how can I change the style of datepicker? color etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have a CSS for bootstrap-datepicker, then you can begin to style it as you wish !